# C# How to get messages from channel/contact using Telegram API (not Bot API)

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-api

I found many examples using the bot api, however I need a simple client that implements an event when a message from a contact or group is received, as a user and not a bot (so the Telegram api, and not Bot api). TLSharp library doesn't implement this method.
What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: how about checking this https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/580

Comment: good starting point... I am going to implement the suggestions from this issue workaround and provide the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided link is old but it was a good starting point. Here is the updated working code:

```
 while (true)
            {
                var state = await _client.SendRequestAsync<TLState>(new TLRequestGetState());
                TrackingState = state.Pts.ToString();
                var req = new TLRequestGetDifference() { Date = state.Date, Pts = state.Pts-10, Qts = state.Qts };
                var diff = await _client.SendRequestAsync<TLAbsDifference>(req);
                var msgs = diff as TLDifference;
                if (msgs!=null && msgs.NewMessages.Count>0)
                {
                    var mss = msgs.NewMessages.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLMessage))
                        .Cast<TLMessage>().ToList().Where(x => x.Date > _lastMessageStamp && x.Out == false)
                        .OrderBy(dt => dt.Date);

                    foreach (TLMessage upd in mss)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("New message ({0}): {1}", upd.Date, upd.Message);
                    }
                    _lastMessageStamp = mss.Any() ? mss.Max(x => x.Date) : _lastMessageStamp;
                }
                await Task.Delay(2500);
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is now [WTelegramClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/), using the latest Telegram Client API protocol (connecting as a user, not bot).

The library is very complete but also very simple to use. Follow the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient#readme) for an easy introduction.

To monitor Update events that are pushed to the client whenever a message is posted somewhere (or other events), take a look at the [Examples\Program_ListenUpdate.cs](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/Examples/Program_ListenUpdates.cs). It demonstrates how to print most events, including messages posted in groups/channels/private chats